# How to fix "This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above." error?

Tags: vue.js, npm

I'm trying to create a project using Vue CLI. But I received this error message:

```
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:58:26)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1440:12)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:58:17)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! hello-world@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the hello-world@0.1.0 serve script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/jeong-ugim/.npm/_logs/2019-04-09T03_17_05_336Z-debug.log
```

I just followed the installation step on "https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html". I did `npm install -g @vue/cli` and `vue create hello-world`. As soon as I committed `npm run serve`, the error message showed up. I looked at the error log, but I couldn't find out what caused my problem.

I tried to update npm. I just can't find what is wrong with my computer or code.

How can I fix this problem? Thank you for any help or suggestion.

This is the error log.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/Users/jeong-ugim/.nvm/versions/node/v11.12.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/Users/jeong-ugim/.nvm/versions/node/v11.12.0/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'serve' ]
2 info using npm@6.7.0
3 info using node@v11.12.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'preserve', 'serve', 'postserve' ]
5 info lifecycle hello-world@0.1.0~preserve: hello-world@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle hello-world@0.1.0~serve: hello-world@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle hello-world@0.1.0~serve: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle hello-world@0.1.0~serve: PATH: /Users/jeong-ugim/.nvm/versions/node/v11.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/jeong-ugim/Programming/hello-world/node_modules/.bin:/Users/jeong-ugim/.nvm/versions/node/v11.12.0/bin:/Users/jeong-ugim/anaconda3/bin:/Users/jeong-ugim/anaconda3/condabin:/Users/jeong-ugim/anaconda/bin:/Users/jeong-ugim/anaconda/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Users/jeong-ugim/anaconda/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
9 verbose lifecycle hello-world@0.1.0~serve: CWD: /Users/jeong-ugim/Programming/hello-world
10 silly lifecycle hello-world@0.1.0~serve: Args: [ '-c', 'vue-cli-service serve' ]
11 silly lifecycle hello-world@0.1.0~serve: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle hello-world@0.1.0~serve: Failed to exec serve script
13 verbose stack Error: hello-world@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/jeong-ugim/.nvm/versions/node/v11.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:197:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/jeong-ugim/.nvm/versions/node/v11.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:197:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:988:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:265:5)
14 verbose pkgid hello-world@0.1.0
```

Comment: Can u add here the "scripts" part of your package.json?

Comment: May be installation problem. If there was Vue CLI 2 in your system you must delete it entirely  then install 3rd version of CLI.  Guess the node version problem like mentioned in this link (https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/5133) . Just try these and tell if problem solved or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @Riddhi and @WebMan. I resolved my issue through setting `auto_activate_base` to be False.

This is the code I used: `conda config --set auto_activate_base False`

I can't still understand why I needed to disable (base) in front of my terminal prompt. But everything seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a complex folder name `(12.abc-def & Workflow blah blah.)` => I used a normal folder name and it works as intended.